# IOS - CNContactPickerViewController should display only the names that has an email?

Tags: ios, swift, email, contacts

I just want to get the name and email from the mobile contact and print it. I'm using the following code to do this task.

```
import UIKit
import ContactsUI
class ViewController: UIViewController, CNContactPickerDelegate{

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        }


        @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any)
        {
            let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
            contactPicker.delegate = self
            contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys =
                [CNContactNicknameKey
                  ,CNContactEmailAddressesKey]

            self.present(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        func contactPicker(_ picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelect contact: CNContact)
        {
            if let emailValue : CNLabeledValue = contact.emailAddresses.first
            {
                print(emailValue.value as String)
            }

            print(contact.givenName + " " + contact.familyName)

        }
    }
```

It prints the name and email that I select in CNContactPickerViewController, even if the selected name does not have an email, it just prints the name alone.
Now, what i want is, I don't want to display the names that has no email, in the CNContactPickerViewController. Only names that has email stored along with it, should be displayed. How can i do that ?

Using Xcode 8.2, Swift 3, IOS 10

**NOTE:** I don't want to check whether the email exists or not, or is it valid or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried adding a predicate to the CNContactPickerViewController? The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contactsui/cncontactpickerviewcontroller/1619201-predicateforenablingcontact) appears to have exactly the requirement that you're looking for.

In your `button()` method add the following before calling `present()`.

```
contactPicker.predicateForEnablingContact = NSPredicate(format: "emailAddresses.@count > 0")
```

Comment: The contact is still displayed, only grayed.

Comment: is it possible that it displays contacts which has an email??